# Saving ids in the cookies and passing them to ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies, checkbox, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate in order to list huge number of files. I also have a check_box in order to choose files for the futher analysis.
To save the ids in the cookie while changing the pages I used following javascript:

```
 <script src="/assets/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
var checkedIds = []

$('.checkmeplease').on("change", function(){ 

   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       checkedIds.push($(this).val())

   }
    else  {
       checkedIds.splice(checkedIds.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);

   }
    $.cookie('checked_file_ids', checkedIds,{path:'/'});
 });


 </script>
```

My checkboxes:

```
 <% @files.each do |file| %>   
 <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id,false,:class=>'checkmeplease'  %></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= file.name %></p> 
 <%end%>
```

It saves the IDs but when I change the page with will_pagination, the saved IDs disappear.
I do not load the previously saved IDs from the cookie. I have found little information about how to pass a javascript variable to ruby or how to catch a `$.cookie('checkedIds')` in the ruby.

How is it possible to do?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *pass* Javascript variable to Ruby or anything else for that matter.

You can, in this particular case, access on server (ruby) side the "checkedIds" cookie value that you've previously set using Javascript on client side. In Rails that would be as easy as `cookies[:checkedIds]`

On ruby side, use the value of the cookie to generate content of your choosing.

Comment: Using cookies[:checkedIds] or value of cookie in ruby will give me only IDs save from the last page. IDs from the first pages is overwriten. By changing the pages and checkboxing new files ,the values of the cookie are overwriten, so I cannot access all files that were checked in all pages. And I am not sure how I can load the previously stored IDs and save them on javascript/rails or ruby, so that at the end I will have all checked IDs

Comment: Ok, than it's a matter of decision if you want to store the id value after every check (you can use ajax for that - send over the checked id on every click and save it on ruby side (in database or whatever)), or you can make some kind of throttling, where you keep a list of clicked id-s and send them every now and then. Other ideas might involve using multiple cookies (for example one cookie per page, each storing a list of clicked ids on that page) or using one large cookie (beware of 4K limit) with a list of all ids clicked.

Comment: Multiple cookies would be good but I do not know how to detect the current page in will_paginate and how to separate javascript as while changing the pages the javascript is loaded new, so the prevous information is lost. Ajax would be good but I guess it will require more work and time as I will have to detect if the checked files were unchecked and reload the ajax. Throttling? A list of checked ids would be good, but I am doing it alreafdy with the above javascript my problem is only that I do not load the previous ids